# Export coordinates from a math function to a .txt file in C++

Tags: function, math, export

My task is to take a math function, such as

```
f(x) = 10 ∗ sin(x)
```

and export a subset of its coordinates into a .txt file. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. When asking a question it is better to *show what research you have done* into your problem and post any *code* or *errors* if it applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export the coordinates into a text file by using `std::ofstream`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

double func(int x){
    return 10 * sin(x); // your function here
}

int main(){
    ofstream fout("coordinates.txt"); // declares an output file stream to 
                                      // "coordinates.txt" called fout

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
        fout << i << ": " << func(i) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```